# Objective-C calling method that been inherited from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, multiple-inheritance

I can't get my left sider class to interact with the view controller ivars methods, i think it may be to do multiple inheritance but i ain't got a clue on how to refactor this to solve my problem…

JACenterViewController  -> inherits CustomClass.h // create object using alloc/init…

JALeft -> inherit JACenterViewController // i would like to say [viewController myCustomClass] helloDelegate];

View Controller class:

```
#import "CustomClass.h"
@interface JACenterViewController : UIViewController <CustomClassDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomClass *myCustomClass;

-(void)pushMe;
@end


#import "JACenterViewController.h"
@implementation JACenterViewController
@synthesize myCustomClass;

// delegrate method
-(void)sayHello:(CustomClass *)customClass {
    [customClass helloDelegate];
}

// class method
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myCustomClass = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
    [self.myCustomClass setDelegate:self];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.myCustomClass createButton]];
}

-(void)pushMe {
    NSLog(@"push me %@", [self class]);
    [myCustomClass helloDelegate];
}
@end
```

my Custom class that VC is inheriting:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class CustomClass;

@protocol CustomClassDelegate
-(void)sayHello:(CustomClass *)customClass;
@end


@interface CustomClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
@property UIButton *button;

-(void)helloDelegate;
-(UIButton*)createButton;
@end


#import "CustomClass.h"
@implementation CustomClass
@synthesize delegate, button;


-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

-(void)helloDelegate {
    NSLog(@"Hello Delegate working!!: %@", [self class]);
    [self.button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(UIButton*)createButton {
    self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [self.button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    return self.button;
}
@end
```

And my finally the my left side class (BTW: this class loads from a storyboard):

```
#import "JACenterViewController.h"
@interface JALeft : UIViewController

@end

#import "JALeft.h"

@implementation JALeft

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    JACenterViewController *viewController = [[JACenterViewController alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"Respones %d", [[viewController myCustomClass] respondsToSelector:@selector(helloDelegate)]);
    NSLog(@"Respones %d", [self respondsToSelector:@selector(helloDelegate)]);
    NSLog(@"Respones %d", [super respondsToSelector:@selector(helloDelegate)]);

    /* NOT WORKING: Method should call customClass methods that has been inherited from ViewController */
    [[viewController myCustomClass] helloDelegate];
}

@end
```

I would like my JALeft class to call a method helloDelegate from the view controller class as it been inherited?

Comment: To call a method in an inherited class you call the method.  Was there another question?  Was there an error message?

Comment: What is expected and actual behaviour? I get a faint clue on expected, and would like to know what is the actual behaviour.

Comment: There no compiler error at all, i would like to call helloDelegate from my JALeft class. if you take a look at my JALeft class u see i cant get any respones allways return 0

Comment: Probably because you're making the call with a nil pointer.

Comment: @HotLicks which line of code are you referring to?

Comment: The line of code that returns zero.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Singleton:
A class that always returns the same instances of itself. it provides a global access point for all the resources within the class.

in CustomClass.h: add

```
+(CustomClass*)sharedObject;
```

in CustomClass.m: add

```
static CustomClass *sharedSingleton = nil;

+(CustomClass*)sharedObject {
        @synchronized(self) {
        if (!sharedSingleton) {
                sharedSingleton = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
            } return sharedSingleton;
        }
}

+(id)alloc {
        @synchronized(self) {
            NSAssert(sharedSingleton == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton");
                sharedSingleton = [super alloc];
                return sharedSingleton;
            } return nil;
```

}

Any class you like to pass and receive messages include this header file in that class and initialize with the factory method .

Comment: I think he's wanting a delegate rather than a singleton - quite different things really.

Comment: @half_brick - Ah, but singletons are the answer to every question.

Answer (score 0):

The first line should theoretically work, but you're not instantiating your JACenterViewController in such a way that viewDidLoad will be called - and therefor your CustomClass instance is not loaded.

To ensure that viewDidLoad is called, instantiate your JACenterViewController with a nib.
Probably like

`JACenterViewController *viewController = [[JACenterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

That way your viewDidLoad will be called and you should then get your delegate instantiated.

Comment: am currently using storyboard so i translated for code into this:
NSString *deviceMode = [[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:deviceMode bundle:nil];

ViewController *viewcontroller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];

But still cant touch the inherited object methods i.e if i called a method on the view controller it works BUT if i called a method helloDelegate from view controller i dont get any respones from my left class